# Why can't I set the value of an Angular Material radio group from my component?

Tags: data-binding, angular-material, radio-group

I've wrestled with this problem twice now, so I'm putting it here to remind future me.  If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'm happy to mark that as the answer.

I'm working on a component that can present options either as radio buttons or as check boxes.  Everything worked well until I tried to add a Cancel feature, and I found that I couldn't set the radio buttons from my component's Cancel function.  When I inspected the value of the variable bound to the Angular Material radio group, it looked right in the dev tools, but it wasn't showing the right option as selected on the screen.

Here is a blitz with an example: https://radio-group-example.stackblitz.io

When it first comes up, it asks you to pick your favorite member of the band Rush.  It defaults to Neil Peart.  Pick whoever you want, and it shows you their name at the top.  But, if you click the "Pick Geddy" button, you'll see that his name appears correctly but there is no radio button selected.

[image: Is Geddy selected or not?]

Also, if you switch from radio buttons to checkboxes and back with the "Switch Widgets" button, it clears all selections.  You can pick members and see their names with the checkboxes, but if you try the "Pick Geddy" button, you'll see that it shows his name but none of the check boxes are selected.

Here is the function for picking Geddy:

```
private changeToGeddy() {
  let weinrib = { name: 'Geddy Lee', id: 'GL' };
  if (this.mutuallyExclusive) {
    this.selectedOptions = weinrib;
  } else {
    this.selectedOptions = [weinrib];
  }
}
```

The question is: Why isn't a selection showing for the radio buttons or the check boxes when the bound variable appears to have the correct value?  Also, what does switching between check boxes and radio buttons have to do with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues at play here - one has to do with switching between mutually exclusive options (radio buttons) and multiple options (check boxes).  The other has to do with binding to either an object or an array.

Here is a blitz with a solution: https://radio-group-example-solution.stackblitz.io

### Managing Radio Buttons and Check Boxes in the Same Widget

First, I have an array of Options in the component that looks like this:

```
options: Option[] = [
  { name: 'Geddy Lee', id: 'GL' },
  { name: 'Alex Lifeson', id: 'AL' },
  { name: 'Neil Peart', id: 'RP' }
];
```

There is also a selectedOptions variable for the component to bind to.  The ngOnInit() function sets it, like this:

```
selectedOptions: Option | Option[];
...
ngOnInit(){
  this.mutuallyExclusive = true;
  this.selectedOptions = this.options[2];
}
```

Here, `this.selectedOptions` can either be an Option object or an array of Option objects.  In this case, I've set each `mat-radio-button`'s value to be an object.  the `mat-radio-group` updates the bound variable with the radio button's value - in this case the Option object.

The `mat-selection-list` widget I'm using for the checkboxes, however, binds not to an object but to an array of objects.  It updates the array to include the set of currently selected objects.  What got me to this problem in the first place was trying to keep track of whether `this.selectedOptions` was object or an array of objects.

Instead, it's much easier to have `this.selectedOptions` always be an array.  Bind the `mat-radio-group` to the first spot in that array, like this:

```
<mat-radio-group name="ralph" [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions[0]">
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
    {{ option.name }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

This way my component is easier to read because I can get rid of the logic dealing with figuring out whether I'm binding to an object or an array.  So if you're dealing with both kinds of widget in a single component, this is one way to manage it.

### Setting Selected Variables by Reference

The other problem was that I was trying to set the value from the component by setting it to an object with the same keys and values rather than using a reference to the original options.

Even if the object is identical in terms of its keys and values, Angular Material does not consider it to be the same object.  If your set of options is coming from an array, to set it programmatically you need to do it by pointing to the actual option, not an identical clone of it.  So, this results in the controls properly reflecting the value of the bound variable:

```
private changeToGeddy() {
  let weinrib = this.options[0];
  this.selectedOptions = [weinrib];
}
```

The function is both shorter and easier to read because we're always binding to an array.  (We don't really need the `let` statement there, but it highlights the fact that we're setting it by reference rather than an object.)